# Start java web application under weblogic --> error

Tags: java, struts2, weblogic

I have used jdk 1.6 to compile my java web application project. 
After war file made, I upload this war to weblogic for deployment.
When I started this application, it show below error.

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter :
>   unsupported classversion 51.0

Do you know why??

Comment: My weblogic server is running on JRockit jdk 1.6. Linux OS jdk is 1.4 --> Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to what is written in there:
[How to fix java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Unsupported major.minor version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-unsupported-major-minor-versi)
your struts library is compiled by `Java SE 7 = 51`.

What you can do is:

- get older library of struts compiled by Java 6
- upgrade jrockit/jdk to 1.7

Comment: Thanks, it is what you said. I have solved